# Raspberry Pi: How to get RPi.GIPO working with Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-3.6

I have installed Python 3.6 using the instructions at https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f

For reasons I don't fully understand Python 3.6.5 was placed in

```
/home/pi/Python-3.6.5
```

and some modules were not available.

I installed RPi.GPIO into /home/pi/Python-3.6.5/Lib using

```
pip install RPi.GPIO -t .
```

Attempting to run a script with sudo python3.6 /home/pi/PythonProjects/omxcall_radar.py produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/PythonProjects/omxcall_radar.py", line 18, in <module>
  import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

However the RPi directory is in the Lib directory

I am working at the limit of my linux skills. Can someone please explain why I am getting the error and/or what I may have done wrong in installing Python 3.6/RPi.GIPO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here.

The `Python-3.6.5` directory in `/home/pi` is the Python *source code*.  It's there because that's where you unpacked the `Python-3.6.5.tar.xz` archive you retrieved using `wget`.  It is *not* where Python was installed.

When you ran `sudo make altinstall`, that installed Python into `/usr/local` (specifically, the binary itself would be `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`).

When you ran `pip install RPi.GPIO -t .`, you installed the `RPi.GPIO` module into your current directory, but that's not anywhere that your newly installed Python would look for it.  Additionally, the `pip` you were using doesn't know anything about your new Python install, either.

After running `make altinstall`, you should probably do the following:

1. Install `pip` for your new Python install:

   ```
   easy_install-3.6 pip
   ```
2. Use `pip3.6` to install `RPi.GPIO`:

   ```
   pip3.6 install RPi.GPIO
   ```
3. Finally, run your script using your new Python:

   ```
   python3.6 /home/pi/PythonProjects/omxcall_radar.py
   ```

You may or may not need `sudo`, depending on what sort of access your script requires.

Comment: This approach worked well after I realized I needed an ssl module to get pip3.6 to install properly. Thanks for the great explanation larsks!